# как получить начало массива в консоли

Tags: php, yii2

Работаю над чужим парсером. Его работу проверяю в консоли. Мне приходит из файла-прайса здоровенный массив. После запуска скрипта парсер начинает формировать этот массив и в консоли это всё отображается. Но... массив большой и его начало образается консолью. Т.е. после формирования этого массива я не могу увидеть его начало, а вижу только хвост.
Пробовал ограничиться через foreach, for, но в силу того, что я не знаю структуры этого массива не уверен, что это лучший метод. Я даже не знаю исчерпывающий перечень ключей, которые в нём есть. Как мне увидеть структуру, выкинув аналогичные элементы, чтоб получилось что-то типа

```
array => [
   'cats' => [
        '0' => [
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'Игрушки',
        ],
        1 - 3000 - пропущено
    ],
   'products' => [
        '0' => [
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'Мяч',
        ],
        1 - 30000 - пропущено
    ],
   'vendor' => [
        '0' => [
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'Бемби',
        ],
        1 - 30 - пропущено
    ],
]
```

Конечно, можно попытаться вычитать код, но сильно уж много условий, которыми данные мнуться и передаются из методов в метод. Это как крайний вариант.

Comment: Провозился до ночи, не решил, но когда дописывал вопрос, пришла идея через array_keys. Вроде можно всё отследить. Решил всё-таки вопрос оставить, вдруг кому-то пригодиться или кто-то даст более красивое решение.

Comment: да, походу конструкция
---
print_r(array_keys($arr));
print_r($arr['currencies']);die();
---
практически решает мою задачу. В идеале получить структуру ключей многомерного массива, чтоб не рыскать по каждому)

Comment: А покажите, какие у Вас данные на входе и какие хотите на выходе - сделаем.)

Comment: `php script.php > log.txt`

Comment: сохраните в json да посмотрите в каком-нибудь редакторе, notepad++ плагины имеет для визуализации дерева

Comment: Denis640Kb, штука в том, что то, что на входе формируется в 15-ти местах, довольно громоздко сюда писать, а что надо на выходе я описал в вопросе. Мне казалось, что есть какой-то метод сделать нужно изящно и удобно. Как я вижу из комментов каждый костылит как может.
u_mulder, teran - переносить вывод консоли в отдельное окно и там его распознавать - да, способ, но он же не удобный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам надо это временно, что бы отладить скрипт а потом это не надо то предложенный выше вариант самый нормальный, писать в файл и отдельно просматривать хоть в консоли постранично (| more или less) хоть где, только можно что-то более удобное для просмотра использовать а не json например вывод php команды var_export.

Как ещё вариант можно обрабатывать дополнительные параметры которые указывать при вызове консольного скрипта и обрабатывать как угодно выводя что угодно.

Если нужно именно как у вас в примере вывод то можно так:

```
<?
$array = array(
    'cats' => array(
        array(
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'test1'
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 2,
            'name' => 'test2'
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 3,
            'name' => 'test3'
        ),
    ),    
    'cats2' =>array(
        array(
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'test4'
        ),
         array(
            'id' => 2,
            'name' => 'test5'
        ),
    ),    
    'cats3' => array(
        array(
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'test6'
        ),
         array(
            'id' => 2,
            'name' => 'test7'
        ),
         array(
            'id' => 3,
            'name' => 'test8'
        ),
         array(
            'id' => 4,
            'name' => 'test9'
        ),
    ),    
);

$showInfoArray = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $arValue) {
    $showInfoArray[$key]['allCountElements'] = count($arValue);
    $showInfoArray[$key]['firstElement'] = array_shift($arValue);
}

var_export($showInfoArray);
```

в консоле вывод будет такой:

```
array (
  'cats' =>
  array (
    'allCountElements' => 3,
    'firstElement' =>
    array (
      'id' => 1,
      'name' => 'test1',
    ),
  ),
  'cats2' =>
  array (
    'allCountElements' => 2,
    'firstElement' =>
    array (
      'id' => 1,
      'name' => 'test4',
    ),
  ),
  'cats3' =>
  array (
    'allCountElements' => 4,
    'firstElement' =>
    array (
      'id' => 1,
      'name' => 'test6',
    ),
  ),
)
```